# How can I create recurring events in Calendar?

Tags: calendar

Does the default calendar app in Ubuntu 16.04 provide an option to create recurring events?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is *not* possible with the default Calendar application but there is an application called 'California' which borrows the look of the default application and extends its functionality. Install as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install california
```

And it certainly has the ability to create recurring events as this screenshot from my Xenial installation demonstrates:

[image]

**References:**

- [Gnome.org: California](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/California)